# Redirect to Login page on session expiry in Asp.Net MVC5 Jquery Mobile application

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on Asp.Net MVC 5 Jquery Mobile application. I am having problem with redirection of page at session expiry.

For example user is on home page. When session is expired and I refresh the page using F5, it redirects me to login page again. that is fine, but after session expiry if I do not press F5 and try to click a link to redirect me to another page, instead of redirecting me to login page, it show a white html page with word "undefined".

I guess this is JQuery Mobile thing. How can I redirect to login page when user perform any activity after session expiry in Asp.Net MVC5 Jquery Mobile application.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15.0) 
});
```

Any help?

Comment: Did you put Authorize attribute in your controller or in the specified action method?

Comment: Yes I have put this at controller level.

Comment: Are you invoking the other pages through jquery ajax call?

Comment: I am not using ajax call. I am just clicking on this link. 

<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "DutyRoaster")">Duty Rosters</a>